# JD L110 cranks but does not start

Tags: starting, cranks-wont-run, lawnmower, john-deere

My John Deere L110 Riding Mower all of a sudden has decided not to start.  I turn the key and it cranks, but does not start.  By looking at the fuel filter, it appears there is no gas in the filter.  I have verified that the fuel line is flowing well and that there is gasoline in the tank.  The engine has been serviced recently including a new spark plug.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state you have "verified that the fuel line is flowing" ... at what point have you determined it's flowing? Is it at the end where it is at the carb? This would seem weird to me because the fuel filter should be between the tank and the carb, which would mean the fuel *should be flowing* through the filter. I'd suggest you figure out at what point the fuel stops flowing and that will help you diagnose what's going on. I would think if the float was stuck, it wouldn't prevent the filter from having fuel in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear to me that you have identified the main cause of this: Fuel is NOT getting into the engine.

You noted that there doesn't appear to be any fuel in the fuel filter, so the next step is to determine WHY that is the case.

Is there a fuel shut-off valve?
Is there a fuel screen that is blocked?
Is the fuel line pinched or clogged?

What about the carburetor? If it's clogged it will prevent fuel from flowing.  If the float it stuck that will also block fuel from flowing.

Comment: A sticking float or needle valve would be my first guess. I had one of my generators stop working a while ago for exactly that, and a motorcycle I bought this year had dad the carbs cleaned for the same reason - I took them apart since it still wasn't running well, though it turned out to be a damaged fuel pump, probably also related to gumming. Engines that don't run often are prone to accumulation of gum in the float bowl.